# Disk quota full - Cannot start GRASS GIS from command line

Tags: grass-gis, ubuntu

I am trying to start GRASS from the command line (I am using a server that runs Ubuntu 18.04.6, but I am working from a Windows 10 machine), but I cannot.
From the output of `quota`, it seems like I filled my disk quota usage:

```
Disk quotas for user lisa (uid 1011):
     Filesystem  blocks   quota   limit   grace   files   quota   limit   grace
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv
                11882464* 10000000 12000000    none     401       0       0
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-data
                9857008  40000000 400000000            5802       0       0
```

I don't actually know what `/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv` is, and I don't know how I filled my quota how as I don't have big files.
Running `df -h` gives:

```
Filesystem                         Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv  295G   65G  215G  24% /
/dev/loop0                         220M  220M     0 100% /snap/microk8s/3272
/dev/loop1                         210M  210M     0 100% /snap/microk8s/3052
/dev/loop2                          56M   56M     0 100% /snap/core18/2409
/dev/loop3                         114M  114M     0 100% /snap/core/13308
/dev/loop4                          56M   56M     0 100% /snap/core18/2344
/dev/loop5                         9.0M  9.0M     0 100% /snap/canonical-livepatch/138
/dev/loop6                         114M  114M     0 100% /snap/core/13425
/dev/loop7                         9.0M  9.0M     0 100% /snap/canonical-livepatch/146
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-data        1.9T  1.6T  236G  87% /data
tmpfs                               26G     0   26G   0% /run/user/1011
```

From this output, `/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv` doesn't seem full, nor `/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-data` (that is so big as it contains other people's data), but `/dev/loops` (what are they?) are full.

When trying to start GRASS typing `grass` in the command line, it first threw this error:
`No usable temporary directory found in /tmp /var/tmp /usr/tmp /home/lisa`
I deleted my `.grass7` folder in `/home/lisa`, but I cannot find any grass tmp files in `/tmp`, `/var/tmp`, `/usr/tmp` (this folder does not even exist) or `/home/lisa`. And `/home/lisa` occupies only 176K!

After removing `/home/lisa/.grass7`, this is the error message I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/grass", line 390, in get_grass_config_dir
    os.mkdir(directory)
OSError: [Errno 122] Disk quota exceeded: '/home/lisa/.grass7'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/grass", line 2350, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/bin/grass", line 2122, in main
    grass_config_dir = get_grass_config_dir()
  File "/usr/bin/grass", line 395, in get_grass_config_dir
    _("Failed to create configuration directory '%s' with error: %s")
NameError: name '_' is not defined
Error in sys.excepthook:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport_python_hook.py", line 155, in apport_excepthook
    pr.write(f)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/problem_report.py", line 402, in write
    file.write(v.replace(b'\n', b'\n '))
OSError: [Errno 122] Disk quota exceeded

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport_python_hook.py", line 155, in apport_excepthook
    pr.write(f)
OSError: [Errno 122] Disk quota exceeded

Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/grass", line 390, in get_grass_config_dir
    os.mkdir(directory)
OSError: [Errno 122] Disk quota exceeded: '/home/lisa/.grass7'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/grass", line 2350, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/bin/grass", line 2122, in main
    grass_config_dir = get_grass_config_dir()
  File "/usr/bin/grass", line 395, in get_grass_config_dir
    _("Failed to create configuration directory '%s' with error: %s")
NameError: name '_' is not defined
```

I cannot understand why it throws `OSError: [Errno 122] Disk quota exceeded: '/home/lisa/.grass7'` if `/home/lisa/.grass7` doesn't even exist anymore. `/data/lisa/GRASS` (where I saved my data and where I also think GRASS stores the data I create during my sessions, as there are my `MAPSET`) is only 5GB.

Answer (score 1):

What you're seeing in the quota report are numbers of file system blocks that you have allocated. (The df is irrelevant - it's the quota that is blocking you). THe block size is most likely 4 KB, so with 10 million blocks that comes to 40 GB. (Not much today...). So I think you'll have to go to whoever is managing the server and get a higher quota. Since the file system has 215 GB free from the `df`, there shouldn't be a problem.

But wait: note that you have access to a quota of 400 million blocks = 160 GB on the data filesystem. Make sure that GRASS is pointing to /data/lisa/GRASS when it starts.

One last suggestion: you can use `du -h --max-depth=1` to see which directories are taking the most space.

Comment: Thanks Micha. I didn't know the difference between the blocks and the space. My quota in /home/lisa is 4GB, while my quota in /data/lisa is 400GB. When (hopefully) the problem is solved, how can I make sure that GRASS is pointing to /data/lisa/GRASS when it starts? My MAPSETS are stored there so I guess it already is pointing to /data. du -h --max-depth=1 is quite useful. Still, no hints on which directory is full.

Comment: Here's the output of `quota -s`, with disk space `Disk quotas for user lisa (uid 1011):
     Filesystem   space   quota   limit   grace   files   quota   limit   grace
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv
                 11604M*  9766M  11719M    none     400       0       0
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-data
                  9507M  39063M    382G            3705       0       0`

Comment: Ah, I added an extra 0 to the home directory quota for you :-).  So if it's only 4GB then for sure you need to check all directories in /home/list to see where the stuff is hiding. See edits to the answer.

Comment: Unfortunately, it seems there is no stuff that is hiding... We are running a find command through the whole server to find my files, but for now no additional stuff besides my 176K in /home/lisa and 5GB in /data/lisa is showing. This is definitely a mystery.

Comment: Are you searching for hidden files as well? i.e. `find / -user lisa -name ".*"`

Comment: The command being used is `find / -user lisa -exec du -ch {} + >>/checklisafiles.txt &`, it is still running since yesterday morning but it didn't find anything besides my files. Looking at the output (the .txt), I guess it is not searching for hidden files (however, I run both `find /home -user lisa -name ".*"` and `find /data -user lisa -name ".*"` and found only hidden folders I was already aware of. 
`find / -user lisa -name ".*" -exec du -ch {} + >>/checklisafiles.txt &` by far is producing an empty .txt

Comment: This is getting pretty far from GRASS :-), but if your quota is full you probably cannot create /checklisafiles.txt. Try directing to /data/lisa ....

and further, don't you need a "\;" at the end of the -exec command ??

Comment: Yes definitely, thanks for sticking to it anyways. GRASS was the only programme I was using on the server thus it (I...) likely produced the files filling my quota. 
I didn't explain everything correctly, sorry: `find / -user lisa -exec du -ch {} + >>/checklisafiles.txt &` creates a .txt in another person directory (e.g., `data/micha/`), and they are running the command (I am far away from understanding it) thus I don't know why they didn't put a \ at the end of `-exec`. As for the empty .txt, I tried the command, and it makes sense that the .txt is empty, as I cannot work on `/data/lisa`.

Answer (score 0):

Update: finally found the problem, it wasn't GRASS's fault. They messed up creating my folder in the server and I was not saving my data in my personal storage space as we thought (although the folder existed and it was in the correct directory!), but instead, they were being saved on the system hard drive (where I have only few GB). This is what was filling my quota and thus why I couldn't start GRASS anymore.